# How can node.js bind to loopback IPs that don't exist?

Tags: ubuntu, node.js, loopback

Simple node server started like so:

```
server.listen(8080, '127.0.0.10');
```

This ip address does not exist anywhere in `ifconfig`:

```
sudo ifconfig | grep 127.0.0.10 # No matches
```

I can connect to `127.0.0.10` and reach node, but not any other loopback IP:

```
curl -sS http://127.0.0.10:8080/ # Works
curl -sS http://127.0.0.1:8080/ # curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

I can ping any loopback address (eg `127.0.12.34`) and get a response.

What's going on here, and most importantly, is it safe to use this addresses in production without first creating a new loopback adapter like `lo:1`?

Comment: This is normal for Linux it's just being helpful. Somewhere we have a similar question that this is a duplicate of but I can't find it right now.

Comment: Makes me feel better, I tried to find the answer with a multitude of searches before posting. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Loopback is "127.0.0.1/8" - it responds to everything on the 127/8 network. You can connect only on 127.0.0.10 because that is the only loopback IP that the service is listening on.

Comment: Gotcha. This is only true for 127/8 addresses, or can I also bind to arbitrary addresses locally and use them? Production safe?